# Variant class (named any like in boost::any)

Tags: c++, variant-type

```
#ifndef ANY_H
#define ANY_H

#include <typeinfo>

namespace _notYourNp
{
    struct BaseHolder
    {
        BaseHolder()
        {}

        virtual ~BaseHolder()
        {}

        virtual BaseHolder* clone() = 0;
    };

    template <class T>
    struct Holder : BaseHolder
    {
        Holder(const T& type)
            : m_Content(type)
        {}

        ~Holder()
        {       
        }

        BaseHolder* clone()
        {
            BaseHolder* tmpHolder = new Holder<T>(m_Content);

            return tmpHolder;
        }

        T m_Content;
    };
}

namespace exception
{
    class bad_cast_any
    {};
}

 class Any
 {
 public:

     Any()
        : m_Content(0), m_Type(const_cast<std::type_info*>(&typeid(int)))
     {}

     ~Any()
     {
         if (0 != m_Content)
         {
             delete m_Content;
         }
     }

    template <class T>
    operator T()
    {
        if (const_cast<std::type_info*>(&typeid(T)) != m_Type)
        {
            throw exception::bad_cast_any();
        }

        return static_cast<_notYourNp::Holder<T>*>(m_Content)->m_Content;
    }

    template<class T>
    Any(const T& value)
        : m_Content(0), m_Type(const_cast<std::type_info*>(&typeid(T)))
    {
        if(0 == m_Content)
        {
            m_Content = new _notYourNp::Holder<T>(value);
        }

        if (const_cast<std::type_info*>(&typeid(T)) != m_Type)
        {
            m_Type = const_cast<std::type_info*>(&typeid(T));

            if (0 != m_Content)
            {
                delete m_Content;
            }

            m_Content = new _notYourNp::Holder<T>(value);
        }
        else
        {
            static_cast<_notYourNp::Holder<T>*>(m_Content)->m_Content = value;
        }
    }

    Any(const Any& A)
        : m_Content(0), m_Type(0)
    {
        if (0 != m_Content)
        {
            delete m_Content;
        }
        m_Content = A.m_Content->clone();
        m_Type = A.m_Type;
    }

     template<class T>
     T& operator = (const T& value)
     {
        if(0 == m_Content)
        {
            m_Content = new _notYourNp::Holder<T>(value);
        }

        if (const_cast<std::type_info*>(&typeid(T)) != m_Type)
        {
            m_Type = const_cast<std::type_info*>(&typeid(T));

            if (0 != m_Content)
            {
                delete m_Content;
            }

            m_Content = new _notYourNp::Holder<T>(value);
        }
        else
        {
            static_cast<_notYourNp::Holder<T>*>(m_Content)->m_Content = value;
        }

        return static_cast<_notYourNp::Holder<T>*>(m_Content)->m_Content;
     }

    Any& operator = (const Any& value)
     {
        if (0 != m_Content && value.m_Type != m_Type)
        {
            delete m_Content;
        }

        m_Content = value.m_Content->clone();
        m_Type = value.m_Type;

        return *this;
     }

     template<class T>
     T& get()
     {
        if (const_cast<std::type_info*>(&typeid(T)) != m_Type)
        {
            throw exception::bad_cast_any();
        }

        return static_cast<_notYourNp::Holder<T>*>(m_Content)->m_Content;
     }

 private:

    std::type_info* m_Type;
     _notYourNp::BaseHolder* m_Content;
 };

 template<class T>
 T any_get(Any& any)
 {
     return any.get<T>();
 }

template<class from, class to>
to any_cast(Any& any)
{
    return static_cast<to>(static_cast<from>(any));
}

#endif
```

This is my try of an `Any` class. I would like to have some opinions about it.

Maybe I can answer one questions about the `_notYourNp` namespace before:

I just used it to hide the holder structs from the user and I didn't wanted them in my any class itself (so the name makes no sense --> not your namespace private). I know it's not the best idea I'm working on a better one, and yes I took some ideas from any (Like the name any and the naming `any_cast<>`).

I hope for some ideas, opinions (also bad ones if there are some), but please, if you bring criticism, then only constructive (and yes throw it away is also constructive criticism).

I tried it on vc10, 13 and the cpp droid compiler for Android.

As accurate as I can measure it (by using int = time start //Code\ time stop)
it is surprising fast compared to `boost::any`, I don't know why maybe there is a mistake anywhere.

Usage example:

```
int main()
{
    Any var;
    var = 5;

    int i = var;
    double d = any_cast<int, double>(var);

    std::vector<Any> v;
    v.push_back(5);
    int z = v.at(0);

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT*****
Additional here is how I measured the speed for assigning and reading from my any (not very accurate how I already wrote, but enough to get a relation)

```
    int placeholder;
    double otherPlaceholder;

    clock_t start, end;
    double cpu_time_used;

    start = clock();
    for (unsigned int i = 0; RUNTIMES > i; ++i)
    {
        placeholder = any; //bzw for boost: placeholder = boost::any_cast<int>(any);
        //and for boost::variant: boost::get<int(variant);
    }

    //measuring the speed for getting the value from any
    //for (unsigned int i = 0; RUNTIMES > i; ++i)
    //{
    //  any = placeholder;
    //  any = otherPlaceholder;
    //}

    end = clock();
    cpu_time_used = ((double)(end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    //the 3000000 or 6000000 to get a 0.xx value
    double timing = (cpu_time_used / RUNTIMES) / 3000000
    //double timing = (cpu_time_used / RUNTIMES) / 6000000 for reading speed
```

The performance testing code is not written by me! So no questions about it to me please (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795827/testing-the-performance-of-a-c-app).

And this are the results saved in a log.txt

```
mango::Any assign reference timing: 0.8075 x 10 power( - 6 ) seconds
mango::Any get value reference timing: 0.0466667 x 10 power( - 6 ) seconds
boost::any assign reference timing: 0.931667 x 10 power( - 6 ) seconds
boost::any get value reference timing: 0.353333 x 10 power( - 6 ) seconds
boost::variant assign reference timing: 2.0225 x 10 power( - 6 ) seconds
boost::variant get value reference timing: 0.465 x 10 power( - 6 ) seconds
```

And here is my newer version of Any

```
#ifndef ANY_H
#define ANY_H

#include <typeinfo>

namespace mango
{
    namespace exception
    {
        class bad_cast
        {};
    }

namespace detail
{
    template <class T> void killContent(void* target);
    template <class T> void reproduceAny(void* target, void*& pool);
}

class Any
{
public:

    Any()
        : m_Content(new int), m_ContentType(const_cast<std::type_info*>(&typeid(int))), kill(&detail::killContent<int>), reproduceAnyContent(&detail::reproduceAny<int>)
    {}

    ~Any()
    {
        if (nullptr != m_Content)
        {
            kill(m_Content);
        }
    }

    template<class T>
    operator T&()
    {
        if (const_cast<std::type_info*>(&typeid(T)) != m_ContentType)
        {
            throw exception::bad_cast_any();
        }

        return *static_cast<T*>(m_Content);
    }

    template<class T>
    Any(const T& value)
        : m_Content(new T(value)), m_ContentType(const_cast<std::type_info*>(&typeid(T))), kill(&detail::killContent<T>), reproduceAnyContent(&detail::reproduceAny<T>)
    {
        if (nullptr == m_Content)
        {
            m_Content = new T(value);

            kill = &detail::killContent<T>;
            reproduceAnyContent = &detail::reproduceAny<T>;
        }

        if (const_cast<std::type_info*>(&typeid(T)) != m_ContentType)
        {
            m_ContentType = const_cast<std::type_info*>(&typeid(T));

            if (nullptr != m_Content)
            {
                kill(m_Content);
            }

            m_Content = new T(value);

            kill = &detail::killContent<T>;
            reproduceAnyContent = &detail::reproduceAny<T>;
        }
        else
        {
            *static_cast<T*>(m_Content) = value;
        }
    }

    Any(const Any& C)
        : m_Content(nullptr), m_ContentType(nullptr), kill(nullptr), reproduceAnyContent(nullptr)
    {
        if (nullptr != m_Content)
        {
            kill(m_Content);
        }

        reproduceAnyContent(C.m_Content, m_Content);

        kill = C.kill;
        reproduceAnyContent = C.reproduceAnyContent;

        m_ContentType = C.m_ContentType;
    }

    template<class T>
    T& operator = (const T& value)
    {
        if (nullptr == m_Content)
        {
            m_Content = new T(value);

            kill = &detail::killContent<T>;
            reproduceAnyContent = &detail::reproduceAny<T>;
        }

        if (const_cast<std::type_info*>(&typeid(T)) != m_ContentType)
        {
            m_ContentType = const_cast<std::type_info*>(&typeid(T));

            if (nullptr != m_Content)
            {
                kill(m_Content);
            }

            m_Content = new T(value);

            kill = &detail::killContent<T>;
            reproduceAnyContent = &detail::reproduceAny<T>;
        }
        else
        {
            *static_cast<T*>(m_Content) = value;
        }

        return *static_cast<T*>(m_Content);
    }

    Any& operator = (const Any& value)
    {
        if (nullptr != m_Content)
        {
            kill(m_Content);
        }

        reproduceAnyContent(value.m_Content, m_Content);

        kill = value.kill;
        reproduceAnyContent = value.reproduceAnyContent;

        m_ContentType = value.m_ContentType;

        return *this;
    }

    template<class T>
    T& get()
    {
        if (const_cast<std::type_info*>(&typeid(T)) != m_ContentType)
        {
            throw exception::bad_cast_any();
        }

        return *static_cast<T*>(m_Content);
    }

private:
    void* m_Content;
    std::type_info* m_ContentType;

    void(*kill)(void* target);
    void(*reproduceAnyContent)(void* target, void*& pool);
};

template<class T>
T any_get(Any& any)
{
    return any.get<T>();
}

template<class from, class to>
to any_cast(Any& any)
{
    return static_cast<to>(static_cast<from>(any));
}

namespace detail
{
    template <class T>
    void killContent(void* target)
    {
        delete static_cast<T*>(target);
    }

    template <class T>
    void reproduceAny(void* target, void*& pool)
    {
        pool = new T(*static_cast<T*>(target));
    }
}
}

#endif //Any_H
```

Answer (score 3):

- Your `class Any` class should be in a namespace. Don't pollute the global namespace.
- Your `struct Holder` and `struct BaseHolder` should be private internal classes of `Any`. Don't deliberately confuse people.
- I note that your `Holder::clone()` does a shallow copy. Is this your intention?
- Use `NULL` or (better) `nullptr` instead of 0. <strike>The C++ standard does not guarantee that `0` is a synonym of `NULL`.</strike> This makes it clear that you mean a null pointer instead of a number, gets rid of a possible "magic number", doesn't involve any typecasting (implicit or explicit).

Comment: Okay, the namespace around the `any class` is a good idea you are right but I would like to have a better solution than pack everything else inside the object. If i don't find any other possibilities I'm going to do what you said. The `Holder::clone()` function makes a deep copy of the value `Holder::m_Content`, it's not necessary to make a copy of `m_Type`, because `typeinfo` objects are unique so i just changed the pointer. Last but not least, I think `NULL` is good I'm going to change it. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: "The C++ standard does not guarantee that 0 is a synonym of NULL." It does. C doesn't and could be `0` or `(void*)0`.

Comment: In the newer version I choose `nullptr` but there is a little problem which I don't like on it, I think older compiler wich don't know `C++11` won't compile it (my smartphone with CppDroid for example), so what would be an alternativ for older compiler?

Comment: By the way, `boost::any` solved this with `0`

Comment: @Mango `#if __cplusplus >= 201103L #define nullptr nullptr #else #define nullptr 0 #endif` . They've to be on separate lines though.